# Get value after special character in XSLT

Tags: xslt

I would like to ask for a help in modifying the following XML with XSLT. I want to get value after first " | " character and add as a new node:

**Example input:**

```
<XML>
    <ITEMS>
        <PRODUCT>
            <NAME>Apple</NAME>
            <IMGURL>http://example.com/image2.jpg</IMGURL>
            <CATEGORYTEXT>Category1 | Subcategory | Subsubcategory4</CATEGORYTEXT>
        </PRODUCT>
        <PRODUCT>
            <NAME>Melone</NAME>
            <IMGURL>http://example.com/image.jpg</IMGURL>
            <PRICE>10</PRICE>
            <CATEGORYTEXT>Category3 | Subcategory2 | Subsubcategory4</CATEGORYTEXT>
        </PRODUCT>
    </ITEMS>
</XML>
```

**Example output:**

```
<XML>
    <ITEMS>
        <PRODUCT>
            <NAME>Apple</NAME>
            <IMGURL>http://example.com/image2.jpg</IMGURL>
            <CATEGORYTEXT>Subcategory</CATEGORYTEXT>
        </PRODUCT>
        <PRODUCT>
            <NAME>Apple</NAME>
            <IMGURL>http://example.com/image.jpg</IMGURL>
            <PRICE>13</PRICE>
            <CATEGORY>Subcategory2</CATEGORY>
        </PRODUCT>
    </ITEMS>
</XML>
```

So far I tried:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>
    
    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="CATEGORYTEXT">
        <xsl:variable name="tokenizedList" select="tokenize(., '|')"/>
        <CATEGORY>
            <xsl:value-of select="$tokenizedList[1]"/>
        </CATEGORY>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Your are long enough around to at least tag your question with the XSLT version you use or can use. And looking at the XPath and XSLT string functions in your favourite reference or doc should allow you to also show some attempt.

Comment: This is rather trivial using the `substring-before()` and `substring-after()` functions. Or `tokenize()` if your processor supports it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>
    
    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="CATEGORYTEXT">
        <xsl:variable name="tokenizedList" select="tokenize(., ' \| ')"/>
        <CATEGORY>
            <xsl:value-of select="$tokenizedList[2]"/>
        </CATEGORY>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

"|" is a special character so it must be escaped.

Comment: Actually, this is wrong. It needs to be `$tokenizedList[2]`. And to avoid the surrounding spaces, you should include them in the tokenizing pattern: `tokenize(., ' \| ')`.